# Mongoose array update not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following document in my collection :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58e47622968feb182c4a26b5"
    },
    "pollOptions": [
        {
            "vote": 0,
            "option": "blue"
        },
        {
            "vote": 0,
            "option": "green"
        },
        {
            "vote": 0,
            "option": "red"
        }
    ],
    "polltitle": "what is your favorite color?",
    "user": {
        "username": "mike",
        "email": "mike@email.com",
        "password": "abc",
        "passwordconf": "abc"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

I want to update the vote number based on the user's choice. I could update just the vote number (couldn't get that to work), so I'm trying to update the whole pollOptions array.

Here is below what I did (2 different approaches). I have the pollData array right, with the 3 objects, as in the document above. The query returns the right object as in the document above. However, this does not update the pollOptions array in the DB. Don't understand why this is not working.

```
app.post('/api/poll/:userId/:polltitle/:vote', (req, res) => {
    let pollData = req.body;
    let userId = req.params.userId;
    let polltitle = req.params.polltitle;
    let query = { 'user.username': userId, 'polltitle': polltitle };
    myModel.findOne(query, (err, doc) => {
        doc.pollOptions = pollData;
        doc.save();
    });
})
```

The following does not work either.

```
app.post('/api/poll/:userId/:polltitle/:vote', (req, res) => {
    let pollData = req.body;
    let userId = req.params.userId;
    let polltitle = req.params.polltitle;
    let query = { 'user.username': userId, 'polltitle': polltitle };
    let update = { $set: { 'pollOptions':  pollData } };
    myModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, (err, doc) => {
        res.send(doc);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance for your kind help !

**EDIT** : I believe my query is working fine. I can do a query of another document in the DB, using a different polltitle param in the URL, and it will return the right document object.

I can add an upvote (in my action creator), and the `req.body` of the post request will show the pollOptions array with the upvote. However, the res object show the pollOptions array does not have this upvote. I must be missing something with the update attribute of the findOneAndUpdate function here.

**EDIT 2** : a console log of `pollData` shows me that pollData is an array.

```
[ { option: 'blue', vote: 1 }, { option: 'green', vote: 0 }, { option: 'red', vote: 0 } ]
```

However, a console log of `typeof(pollData)` tells me pollData is an object. Strange. That could be the reason why the update does not work.

Comment: If `req.params.userId` is of type `ObjectId` the query won't work because `user.username` is `String` (`'mike'` in the example)

Comment: A console log of typeof(userId) tells me that userId is a String.

Comment: Yes, of course, my bad, when I said `ObjectId` I meant a 24-character string, something like `5768323d7297115c1606f6ad`

Comment: You can try `let query = { 'user.username': userId, 'polltitle': polltitle,  'pollOptions.option':blue };
    let update = { $inc: { 'pollOptions.$.vote':  1 } };
    myModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, (err, doc) => {
        res.send(doc);
    });` below query for incrementing vote number for a user selected option.

Comment: @Veeram : I tried what you suggested. That didn't work :(

Comment: Can you confirm your input values are all correct ? Check all the input values. Do you get any error ? Try `'pollOptions.option':"blue"`

Comment: @Veeram : yes, I added a `if (err) console.log(err)` in the callback, and it shows no error message unfortunately.

Comment: Can you console log all the input values  and show me your updated query  please ?

Comment: As a database, I use the free plan from mlab's DBAAS. Could there be some restriction with updating documents ?

Comment: I don't think so. You should see error messages in any event.

Comment: @Veeram :

log of req.params :

`{ userId: 'mike', polltitle: 'your favorite color', vote: '0' }`

log of pollData :

`pollData [ { option: 'blue', vote: 1 },
  { option: 'green', vote: 0 },
  { option: 'red', vote: 0 } ]`

log of doc (in the callback) :

`{ _id: 58e47622968feb182c4a26b5,
  pollOptions: 
   [ { option: 'blue', vote: 0 },
     { option: 'green', vote: 0 },
     { option: 'red', vote: 0 } ],
  polltitle: 'your favorite color',
  __v: 0,
  user: 
   { username: 'mike',
     email: 'mike@email.com',
     password: '11',
     passwordconf: '11' } }`

Comment: Thank you but I'm not sure which query you are using. Can you show me the query too ? is that the first query from your post ? Why is `vote` value non numeric in your `req.params` ?

Comment: @Veeram : the `vote` from `req.params` is from the params, so it's unrelated with the actual color vote by the user. I could probably remove this param from the url path. Yes my query is the first thing in the first post. I have several documents in the DB's collection with different polls. The document in the original post above is the result of the query.

Comment: So its just the writes that are not working correct ? Do you have some kind of authentication set up ?

Comment: What I don't understand is that a `console.log(typeof(pollData))` says that pollData is an `object`. Whereas it looks to me like it's an array (an array of objects). If it is an object, well, that could be why the update does not work, updating an array with an object

Comment: No `typeof` array is an `object` also. You've to use `Array.isArray` to differentiate regular objects from arrays. The update should work for the query that you are using  no matter as mongodb doesn't care about type. It will simply overwrite the existing field with new type but that is not your problem. It may be some kind of permission issue. Do you have access to the mongodb server logs ?

Comment: @Veeram : ok, thanks, I didn't know. At least I have learned this :)

I'm not sure what type of test I could do to get clues about what is wrong

Comment: Np. I'm not really familiar with mlab's DBAAS. Did you have to set up some kind of authentication to use with mlab's DBAAS ?

Comment: @Veeram : you have to sign up for a free account to use mlab indeed. This said, I can successfully add the document into the collection with a simple post request in another action creator. Like this :
`app.post('/api/newpoll', (req, res) => { const output = new myModel({user: req.body.user, polls: req.body.polls}); output.save(); res.end(); });`

Comment: @Veeram : ok, I found what was wrong. There was a mistake with my definition of the schema. Silly mistake. All the code above was correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/api/poll/:userId/:polltitle/:vote', (req, res) => {
    let pollData = req.body;
    let userId = req.params.userId;
    let polltitle = req.params.polltitle;
    let query = { 'user.username': userId, 'polltitle': polltitle };
    let update = { $set: { 'pollOptions':  pollData } };
    myModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, (err, doc) => {
        res.send(doc);
    });
});
```

**after update:**

```
"pollOptions" : [ 
        {
            "vote" : 1.0,
            "option" : "blue"
        }, 
        {
            "vote" : 0.0,
            "option" : "green"
        }, 
        {
            "vote" : 0.0,
            "option" : "red"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't see what it is that you modified here.

Comment: i not modified here, i just give solution here.